# jQuery remove class of image when other image is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a jQuery code to insert a border when the image is clicked

```
<div class="span2">

        <div class="text"> 
            <div class="pull-left ">
                <div id="opt" class="btn">
                    <img  class='roller' src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/food-balanced-diet-form-circle-15460029.jpg">
                    <p>img1</p>
                </div>

                <div id="opt" class="btn">
                    <img class='roller' src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/food-balanced-diet-form-circle-15460029.jpg">
                    <p>img2</p>
                </div>

                <div id="opt" class="btn">
                    <img class='roller' src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/food-balanced-diet-form-circle-15460029.jpg">
                    <p>img3</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="text"> 
            <div class="pull-left ">
                <div id="opt" class="btn">
                    <img class='roller' src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/food-balanced-diet-form-circle-15460029.jpg">
                    <p>1</p>
                </div>

                <div id="opt" class="btn">
                    <img class='roller' src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/food-balanced-diet-form-circle-15460029.jpg">
                    <p>2</p>
                </div>

                <div id="opt" class="btn">
                    <img class='roller' src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/food-balanced-diet-form-circle-15460029.jpg">
                    <p>3</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I need to remove that border after the user click on another image.

My code: https://jsfiddle.net/abdL69uv/3/

Comment: so many ways to do that, guys can u tell me what is the right one i mean a good practice of jquery. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could delegate event and use following logic:

```
$('.span12').on('click', '.roller:not(.highlight)', function (e) {
    $(e.delegateTarget).find('.roller.highlight').add(this).toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

### -jsFiddle-

But to be fair, it should be done in CSS only:

```css
.btn input[name=opt] {
    display: none;
}
.roller {
    border: 6px solid transparent;
}
.btn input[name=opt]:checked + .roller {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-color: black;
    -webkit-transition: border-color 600ms;
    /* Safari */
    transition: border-color 600ms;
}
img {
    width:120px;
    height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="span12">
    <div class="text">
        <div class="pull-left ">
            <div class="btn">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="opt">
                    <img class='roller' src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/food-balanced-diet-form-circle-15460029.jpg">
                </label>
                <p>img1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="btn">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="opt">
                    <img class='roller' src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/food-balanced-diet-form-circle-15460029.jpg">
                </label>
                <p>img2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="btn">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="opt">
                    <img class='roller' src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/food-balanced-diet-form-circle-15460029.jpg">
                </label>
                <p>img3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <div class="pull-left ">
            <div class="btn">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="opt">
                    <img class='roller' src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/food-balanced-diet-form-circle-15460029.jpg">
                </label>
                <p>1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="btn">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="opt">
                    <img class='roller' src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/food-balanced-diet-form-circle-15460029.jpg">
                </label>
                <p>2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="btn">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="opt">
                    <img class='roller' src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/food-balanced-diet-form-circle-15460029.jpg">
                </label>
                <p>3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or animating `border-radius` too, for the effect:

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: Nice approach, upvote. Could you explain a little about it to the user asking for help?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$('.roller').on('click', function() {
    $('.roller').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).addClass('highlight'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`.roller` elements are not siblings, so you have to do some DOM traversal to target them.

either do :
    `$(this).addClass('highlight').parent().siblings().find('.roller').removeClass('highlight');`

or

```
$('.roller').removeClass('highlight');
$(this).addClass('highlight');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove your class before adding it to next image.

```
$('.roller').on('click', function() {
    $('.roller').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).addClass('highlight'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.roller').on('click', function() {
   $(this).parent().siblings().find('.roller').removeClass('highlight'); 
   $(this).addClass('highlight');
 });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abdL69uv/6/)

Answer (score 1):

as simple as that

```
$('.roller').on('click', function() {
   $('.roller').removeClass('highlight').filter(this).addClass('highlight'); 
});
```

or using scope to be more faster:

```
$('.roller', '.span12').on('click', function() {
    $('.roller','.span12').removeClass('highlight').filter(this).addClass('highlight'); 
});
```

in case of restricting this in the scope of '.text' class

```
$('.roller', '.span12').on('click', function() { 
    $('.roller',$(this).parents('.text')).removeClass('highlight').filter(this).addClass('highlight'); 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/10w93bp7/

Comment: I don't see such kind of requirement, where did you saw it in the question?

Comment: OK, I'll add a code for sublings as anothere sample